# Facing issue in binding Kendo UI grid with SharePoint list

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-list, gridview, script-webpart

I am facing the issue in binding Kendo UI grid with Sharepoint List.

I am getting following error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).kendoGrid is not a function
```

I have added scripts in the following order,

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Earlier I have asked for script editor but I have tried it in SharePoint Framework also and it is giving the same error there also.

I am using following code :

```
import { SPComponentLoader } from '@microsoft/sp-loader';
import 'kendo-ui-core';


export default class HelloWebArtWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IHelloWebArtWebPartProps> {

private listItemEntityTypeName: string = undefined;
public constructor() {
    super();
   // SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js');
   // SPComponentLoader.loadScript('//emgage21.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/Documents/kendo.all.min.js');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/styles/kendo.common.min.css');
      SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.default.min.css');
  }
  public render(): void { 
   this.domElement.innerHTML = `<div id="example"><input id="grid"/></div>`;

    // this.listItemEntityTypeName = undefined;
    // this.updateStatus(this.listNotConfigured() ? 'Please configure list in Web Part properties' : 'Ready');
    // this.setButtonsState();
    // this.setButtonsEventHandlers();

    this.demo();    
  }
  protected demo():void{

        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
                            },
                            pageSize: 50
                        },
                        height: 850,
                        groupable: false,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true,
                            buttonCount: 15
                        },
                        columns: [{
                            field: "ContactName",
                            title: "Contact Name",
                            width: 200
                        }, {
                            field: "ContactTitle",
                            title: "Contact Title"
                        }, {
                            field: "CompanyName",
                            title: "Company Name"
                        }, {
                            field: "Country",
                            width: 150
                        }]
                    });
                      }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You will get this error if `kendo` JavaScript library failed to load or if you are trying to bind before `kendo` file loading completes.

Please make sure your JavaScript as follows

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    ....
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried the same and getting above mentioned error with this.

Comment: Can you do CTRL + F5 your browser and see Kendo JS file is loading?

Comment: It is loading properly...

Comment: Just to trace your problem can you add a debugger statement in the ready function and see from the browser console if you type kendoGrid

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned in one of my previous answers, you need to use `https://`. In your current example, your `kendo js` is loaded via `http://` . So the browser is blocking this file.

Secondly, your `kendo ui` file version is `2015.1.318` which is only compatible with `jquery 1.10.x or 2.1.x`.

Reference - [JavaScript Prerequisites for Kendo UI](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites)

Thirdly, in my chrome browser, there is some certificate issue with `kendo ui` cdn reference `https://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js`,so i had to change the cdn js file reference.

So, the below code is what is present in my SEWP and its working

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.1.318/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id="example"><input id="grid"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Customers"
            },
            pageSize: 50
        },
        height: 850,
        groupable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 15
        },
        columns: [{
            field: "ContactName",
            title: "Contact Name",
            width: 200
        }, {
            field: "ContactTitle",
            title: "Contact Title"
        }, {
            field: "CompanyName",
            title: "Company Name"
        }, {
            field: "Country",
            width: 150
        }]
    });                     
</script>
```

Check the below screenshot:

[image]

[Refer Kendo UI from CDN with Local Script Fallbacks](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/cdn-service)

Comment: I am still getting the same error.with this code snippet also.

Comment: Can you clear cache ? Check in & publish page ? Also try in another browser? also check and remove if there is any other jquery on the page ? i am using a blank page and its working

Comment: This same thing working for SharePoint 2013 on premises but not working in SharePoint 365.